# Delete all index data/files in disk using Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine, flush

How can I flush/delete/erase all the index files/data in the disk using Apache Lucene.This is my code so far and still I can't remove index files.Please help me out...

Test:

```
public class Test {
    private static final String INDEX_DIR = "/home/amila/Lucene/REST/indexing"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
            ContentIndexer contentIndexer = new ContentIndexer(INDEX_DIR);
            contentIndexer.flushDisk();
            System.out.println("Flushed");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ContentIndexer:

```
public class ContentIndexer {
    private IndexWriter writer;

    public ContentIndexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {

        // create the index
        if (writer == null) {
            writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir)),
                    new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36,
                            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36)));
        }
    }

    public void flushDisk() {
        try {
            writer.deleteAll();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited -- Updated Answer**

```
public class Test {
    private static final String INDEX_DIR = "/home/amila/Lucene/REST/indexing";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36,
                    new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
            conf.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
            Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIR));

            IndexWriter indexWriter  = new IndexWriter(directory, conf);
            indexWriter.deleteAll();
            indexWriter.commit();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is to open `IndexWriter` with a [CREATE mode](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html) (via `indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(...)`). This removes all existing index files in the given directory.

For older versions `IndexWriter` constructor also has a special `boolean create` flag which does the same thing.

Comment: Ok i figured it now.. after the deleteAll() , indexWriter.commit(); should be added..Then it worked like a charm...I have addeed the answer along with the question

Comment: You should probably add your answer as an answer and accept it.

Comment: You were the one who told me the steps ,first place.. so u better add it to your answer!! :)

Comment: Thanks. this is great. However, I see each time the prefix of the names of the files gets incremented by 1 (_0.cfe, _1.cfe, _2.cfe etc). What if I want the file names to be prefixed by 0 each time?

Comment: @AsifIqbal you can't control file names, this is internal to Lucene.

Comment: This solution is a lot more elegant than the `indexWriter.deleteAll(); indexWriter.commit();` suggestion in the question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use two options :

1. You can call the delete all method of the writer

   indexWriter.DeleteAll();
2. You can create a new indexWriter with the create flag set to true  ( open mode= created)

   new IndexWriter(_luceneDirectory, _analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);